# Laravel Show method not working?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.6, and this is my model

```
class Careers extends Model
{
    //
    protected $guarded=[];
}
```

and, I am getting this output from CareersController@show method

```
Careers {#592 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

and the show method is as

```
public function show(Careers $careers)
{
    //        return view('admin.careers.show',['career'=> $careers]);
    dd($careers);
}
```

Even I tried to get output from view its showing blank space.

Comment: You are missing something. Show us the sending form and routes. Maybe there isn't $careers object?

Comment: You have a typo, you pass the `career` variable to the views instead of `careers`

Comment: Add the output for attributes ?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan, I tried to do the same, passing
    careers
to the views but still have the same error.

Comment: @NAK.dev, yes its not showing, any help ?

Comment: @RajanSharma Are you using a valid ID? The dump seems to suggest that there isn't a `Careers` with that ID.

Comment: Careers should be at singular. Show method shows a single resource, based on route bindings, such as /career/{id}. Please check the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: @AlexG., Many Thanks. It worked, renamed, $careers to $career